# AngularJS: Select list manipulation from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dom-manipulation

I am trying to set select list value from angular JS,which doesn't throw any exception but doesn't reflect any changes either. This is my jsp code.

```
<select class="form-control "  id="searchCriteriaList"
                    name="searchCriteriaList" ng-model="searchCriteriaSelect" required>
                    <option>IMEI</option>
                    <option>Registration Number</option>
                </select>
```

This is my angularJS code

```
 var selectedValue = "IMEI";
 $scope.searchCriteriaSelect = selectedValue;
```

This shows a blank select list. Although this code works

```
$scope.searchCriteriaSelect = "IMEI";
```

and select list shows IMEI option on page load.

But I can't assign hardcoded values. It has to be through a variable as data comes from ajax request in my code.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried assigning it to the first index of your list?  Like `searchCriteriaList[0]` or perhaps when you get the result of your `ajax` call, you then assign the model value to the first index?

Comment: this works perfectly normally in a generic angular 1.4.8 app.  http://plnkr.co/edit/HBN6YGdWcobUKqz7Lhe9?p=preview.  Perhaps it has something to do with the version of angular you are using, or something else that is interacting with these values?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you assign the options in the select via the ngoptions directive;
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

```
<select ng-options="item as item for searchCriteriaList" ng-model="searchCriteriaSelect"></select>
```

Then you can have a explicit declaration of searchCriteriaList:

```
var searchCriteriaList = [];
searchCriteriaList.push("IMEI");
```

Then you can track by index:

```
$scope.searchCriteriaSelect = $scope.searchCriteriaList[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
<option value="IMEI">IMEI</option>
<option value="XXX">Registration Number</option>
```

add    **value="IMEI"**    into option attribute